# Getting an 500 internal error when uploading file using cgi and python

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, file-upload, cgi, server

Hi I have a project that involves uploading documents. I am using html for the front end and python for the backend. I've managed to link my html and python file but I'm having a problem with the server. At first I though it was a random thing but I'm pretty sure it's because of what I added to the python code. I have:

```
import cgi
import sys
import os

htmlform = cgi.FieldStorage()
file_data = htmlform['myfile']

if not fileitem.file:
return

(name,ext) = os.path.splitext( fileitem.filename)

#if ext == “.jpg” or ext == “.png” or ext == “.gif”:
#ioFlag = “wb”
#else:
#ioFlag = “w”
```

I was able to log into my page go to the html form submit the form and got to a basic success html page I had below the above input. Now Im pretty new to python and didnt realise that the if statements should be indented. And I get a 500 internal error when I uncommented the if statement. I did it once and then went through commenting out my code being completely confused as to why I was getting error but after a while it just started working again. My guess is the incorrect if statement somehow got it stuck. I expect after about an hour it'll be working again but ideally I'd like to know if I could stop the process on the server if possible. I was following this guide http://www.alwaysgetbetter.com/blog/2009/01/02/python-file-upload/

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it! The problem seems to be the indentation. If you're ever unsure about this stuff look at the error logs. I'm using an apache server and I dont have access to the error logs so I used

```
sudo cat /etc/log/apache2/error.log
```

It gave me the answer and this should hopefully help you even if your question is unrelated.

EDIT: An for completeness sake file_data should be fileitem